# How to format timestamp data to date format in laravel

Tags: laravel, timestamp, date-format, php-carbon

Hello I have laravel project that store data created_at as a timestamp, I would call it from database, but it still show timestamp format, how can I convert it to date format without changing my column type? [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiTFR.png)

here is my model:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->timestamp;
}

//fungsi untuk merubah format tanggal diubah ke timestamp
public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->timestamp;
}
```

and how should I call it in view or .blade file??
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To convert to human readable string try changing your functions as below:

```php
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->toFormattedDateString();
}

//fungsi untuk merubah format tanggal diubah ke timestamp
public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->toFormattedDateString();
}
```

`toFormattedDateString()` function will convert to format like `Jun 22, 2020`. See this article for more alternatives https://www.leonelngande.com/format-dates-for-humans-with-carbon-in-php/.

To use in blade file simply access the parameter like:

```php
$modelvariablename->created_at
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute(): Carbon {
    return Carbon::parse($this->created_at);
}

public function getUpdatedAtAttribute(): Carbon {
    return Carbon::parse($this->created_at);
}
```

For use:

```
$model->created_at->format('d.m.Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the data from controller to blade You can call in your blade file like this ...

```html
<sapn>{{ $variable->updated_at->toDateString() }}</span>
```

Or

```html
<span>{{ $variable->updated_at->format('Y-m-d') }}</span>
```

if you want to convert to inside controller.

```php
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return $value->toDateString();
}
```

fungsi untuk merubah format tanggal diubah ke timestamp

```php
public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return $value->toDateString();
}
```

Or you can try carbon

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;
    
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

fungsi untuk merubah format tanggal diubah ke timestamp

```php
public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use eloquent's [attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) instead.

So for example, make `created_at` shown as date in `d-m-Y` format:

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:d-m-Y'
];
```

Note that attribute casting will only effects the attibute when the model is serialized to json or array (as stated in the doc).